# Two consecutive multiprocessing pool of python paralleling

Tags: python

I try to do two consecutive pools. The example codes are:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

n  = 100
y1 = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float)
y2 = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float)

def f(i,a):
    return i, float(i)+a

def callback1(result):
    i = result[0]
    y1[i] = result[1]

def callback2(result):
    i = result[0]
    y2[i] = result[1]

# pool 1
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
for i in range(n):
    pool.apply_async(f, args=(i,2.0), callback=callback1)   
pool.close()
pool.join()

# pool 2
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
for i in range(n):
    pool.apply_async(f, args=(i,2.0), callback=callback2)   
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Do I need to do something between the first pool and the second pool?

Comment: No, once you've joined the pool its subproceses have exited and no more interaction is needed.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that my real code does not work. To be specific, my second pool is not running and just get dead there.

Comment: I see the opposite problem. Since you don't wait for your `apply_async` work items to complete, your pool may not have run at all. You should append work items to a list `results.append(apply_async(...))` and get the results `for r in results:r.get()` before `pool.join`.

Comment: If you are running on windows, you need to put all of this under an `if __name__ == "__main__":`. When spawning new processes on windows, python will reimport modules and anything at the module level will run a second time.

Comment: You could add logging to your workers to see if they hang or return.